# How to append to element which is not in the DOM object

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
function myfunc(){
var feed = "<div><div class='inner'></div></div>";
$(feed).find('.inner').append('<div>some more html here...</div>');
return feed;
}

//append the whole string later o the DOM
$('body).append(myfunc());
```

my problem is the html snippest am appending to **inner** div do not show up

How do I solve this ?

Comment: You do understand that you actually returning `"<div><div class='inner'></div></div>"` form the function (always)? You need to `return $(feed).find('.inner').append('<div>some more html here...</div>').end();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myfunc(){
    var feed = $('<div/>', { html: $('<div/>', { class: "inner" }) });
    $(feed).find('.inner').append($('<div/>', { html: "some more html here..." }));

    return feed;
}

$('body').append(myfunc());
```

and you've missed single quote on the last line.

Comment: obviousely I want myfunc() to return a string like <div><div class='inner'><div>some more html here...</div></div></div>

I tried your answer but it returns [Object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the `feed` which is the html string, appending it `body`. So body rendered the below html

```
<div><div class='inner'></div></div>
```

In your code you did `$(feed)`, it created a new Jquery object, and inside this object you called `find('.inner')`, which found out the dom node and appended the string you asked it to do. But those all happened in memory and never got used after that, as you returned `feed` which was the old html string you were started with.

Rewrite your code as

```js
function myfunc() {
  var $feed = $("<div><div class='inner'></div></div>");
  $feed.find('.inner').append('<div>some more html here...</div>');
  return $feed;
}

//append the whole string later o the DOM
$('body').append(myfunc());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```